# AngularJS DOM / document selections without jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS doesn't have a built in DOM selection engine yet provides utility methods that handle a portion of what jQuery would provide for a typical application.

However, DOM selection is still king and I'm trying to keep jQuery out of my application for the sole purpose of DOM selections.

Angular provides a $document service as an injectable. I find this to be cumbersome. For example, to achieve native DOM selections using $document you would need to inject $document into all directives desired and call querySelectorAll, then extend it with Angular:

```
angular.element( $document[0].querySelectorAll('#element') )
```

This is silly.

In there interim I've provided myself a global helper, but it doesn't use Angular's wrapped $document...

```
  // Create a shortcut to querySelectorAll
  window.query = function(selector) {
    return document.querySelectorAll( selector )
  }

  // For use inside a directive like so...
  angular.element( query('#element') )
```

AngularJS is ALLERGIC to globals and wraps globals for protection and testability. Is there a clean way I can leverage querySelectAll without passing $document into every directive? Can I extend angular.element in the same fashion jQuery does but utilize querySelectorAll?

**Edit:**

I also want to note the original JQLite library supports basic selectors https://code.google.com/p/jqlite/wiki/UsingJQLite#Supported_Selectors.

The AngularJS implementation however does not support selectors nor appears to mention this feature omission - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Instead AngularJS does:

```
throw Error('selectors not implemented');
```

^ when the item passed to angular.element is a string which does not start with '<'.

It'd be nice if that was:

```
return document.querySelectorAll( element )
```

...with some basic error prevention logic.

Comment: Have you thought about using something like [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) instead of full jQuery? (jQuery runs on this internally.)

Comment: I have, and it might be the way to go until Angular adopts a selection pattern. You'll see I've updated the post indicating I wish it'd just return a document.querySelectorAll attempt at the point of the exception. I mean, why not? There's no bloat being added here.

Comment: I should also note that when the Angular team recommends document.querySelectorAll in these cases, they are defecting from their wrapped global patterns which they advocate in places like here - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$window.

Comment: The thing with querySelectorAll / Sizzle is... angular.element is only designed to operate an a single node :(

Comment: I agree on the silly (klunky) nature of Angular and all JS MVCs. I feel it is part the inherent klunk of javascript and also the origins of JS MVC (a lot of rails people). So much code is consistent across Java, C, C++, Python, PHP, etc (not rails) in inheritance and traversing scope/whatever. I consider most of the JS I write for JS MVCs something that would get me fired in other language positions. Class-less prototypical languages just seem to go this way. ```querySelectorAll``` is all we have, for now. Feedback welcome. #thx

Comment: You can use [http://angularui.net/appdoc/documents/home/nojq](http://angularui.net/appdoc/documents/home/nojq) which is light-weight selector engine for angular.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$document` is a wrapper, true. Maybe one of the Angular authors could confirm this, but I think it was not meant to be injected into directives. Neither is `$window`. Its only for the rare conditions and cases where you need to deal with `$window` or `$document` in a `Controller` or a `Service`.

When you are in a directive, the DOM is assumed. So, feel free to use `document` or `window` directly if you wish.

The way angular is designed, you dont need complex selectors. If you are doing a complex selection ( even inside directives ) there is probably a simpler way to do it. Note that the directive gives you access directly to the element to which it is attached. Now you should be concerned mostly with the elements around your element, perhaps elements that are like siblings or direct children. If you are looking for nodes that are somewhere else, then that is the first sign of a "smell".

If you could let us know what you are attempting to achieve, then someone could suggest you a solution that breaks things up nicely.

Comment: Interesting points. The most common scenario I've found is injecting elements, such as stylesheets into the <head> tag from various directives. I see I have other cases where I could get more granular with ng-class directives and such. Perhaps I have been over thinking how $document/$window should be used in the Angular sense. 

Would love to hear from the Angular guys of course.

Comment: This feels odd... but I've added a directive to the <head> element now... neat.